# how to display local database image in browser w react js

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, image

```
        new Product
        {
            Id = 2,
            CategoryId = 2,
            BrandId=5,
            ProductName = "Galaxy S23",
            Stock = 20,
            Price = 24999,
            CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ProductImage= "C:\\Users\\serka\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\Staj\\Ecommerce\\Core\\ProductImages\\s23ımage.jpg"
        },
```

this is my entity session, I added the path to a product image and I want to reflect it on my website in react

```
export const getAllProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await getProductlist();

    const products = response.data.data.map((product) => ({
      id: product.id,
      name: product.productName,
      brand: getBrandNameById(product.brandId),
      price: product.price,
      image: product.productImage,
    }));
    console.log(products);
    return products;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ürün yükleme hatası", error.message);
    return [];
  }
};

const getProductlist = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://localhost:7001/api/Product/All");
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Ürünleri alma hatası: " + error.message);
  }
};
```

```
        <ul className="product-list">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <ProductItem
              key={product.id}
              imageSrc={product.image}
              name={product.name}
              brand={product.brand}
              price={product.price}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
```

```
const ProductItem = ({ imageSrc, name, price, brand }) => {
  console.log(imageSrc);
  return (
    <li className="product-item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src={imageSrc} alt="" className="product-image" />
        <h3 className="Product-name"> {name} </h3>
        <p className="product-price"> {price} TL</p>
        <p className="product-brand"> Marka:{brand}</p>
        <button className="product-cart-button"> Sepete Ekle </button>
      </a>
    </li>
  );
};
```

[console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iiq4.png)

Above are the productItem blocks where I transferred my seed, api connection and data to the peer, I cannot print my image on my page, what path should I follow?

I took an "https" link from google drive and assigned it, I also paid attention that the link was public, but I could not get an image again, I tried both ways with replaceAll to change the "//" signs to "" and "/", I have not found a solution yet, I am waiting for your help, thanks.

Comment: The links were not public, the console log image shows that your files have local path "C://..."

Comment: @quyentho the public link I mentioned is different, there I put the image when I tried the local one, my public link was a google drive link starting with https, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I converted my images into code via base64.guru and embedded them in my database in string type. Then on react side src={`data:image/*;base64, ${imageSrc}`}
I did a process in the form of. I was able to open my images on my site by introducing the incoming base64 data.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, images from local drive (your device) can not be accessed through url. You have to upload the image in a bucket like s3 or on a folder (your projects public folder can be used) inside server. Then create a url for that image and pass that image url to the `<img/>`. That way you can access it.

Any image outside public folder can not be accessed by the project without importing it first.

Comment: When I put it in the public folder, it is like a static structure that I will have to manually assign the image of each product, since I am trying to build a dynamic system, I am trying to pull an image directly from the database.

Comment: What your db has is a url to image. And that url is not accessible by the project. Your actual image must be somewhere , where it can be accessed by your project. So when creating the product , upload the image first , then create the url and assign the url in the product. that way it will not be static. If it is coming from an API then the image should be in a bucket or in the server. That way the url will be accessible. Your image location is the main issue here.